# Does it make sense to populate an AntiForgeryToken in Login/Register forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I hope my question is not too simple, but you know when it comes to security, we all get skeptic.

Since before these two cases (login/registration), we don't have a logged-in user (a session cookie), Why would we bother having an AntiForgeryToken in login/register form?

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you don't. The attack you're talking about is a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). This type of attack relies on a logged-in user (if you're logged in to site A and site B and site A knows this, they could put html code in that would cause a request to go to site B that would look like you initiated it and may cause for a sensitive action to be performed). These attacks rely on the browser sending the session cookie/token with all requests to the site in question (site A includes a request to site B to do action X, which causes the browser to send a request to site B, thus including all cookies, including session cookies, to be sent to site B with that request).

The anti-CSRF tokens work because when you send a request form to a client, you include an unguessable value that the client must send back with their action request. If it comes back, you know that the request for an action to be performed originated with a form you sent to the client. If it does not come back, the request may be forged, so you should ignore it. If code on site A caused a request to be sent to site B, even with the session cookie for site B, the code on site A would not know the anti-CSRF token value to include, so the faked request would be rejected.

So, if you are trying to guard against CSRF attacks on your site, you need to include these tokens in all forms that can initiate sensitive actions to prevent forged requests taking advantage of logged-in users. This defense is irrelevant for non-logged in users, as another site cannot take advantage of the fact that a browser would send the session cookie/token with all requests, if a user is not currently logged in.

Comment: Nice explanation of CSRF in plain words!

Comment: I should also point out I said "generally." There is an attack where you may want to do this to mitigate, a variant of CSRF sometimes called "login CSRF." Instead of tricking you to submit a request to a site you're already logged in to, an attacker could trick you into logging into a site using other/not-your credentials so that the site sees you as another user. For example, if he included login code for Google on his unrelated site and your browser saw and executed it, you'd be logged in to Google as an attacker-controlled user. Then, when you search, thinking you  were not logged in,

Comment: you really would be and Google would be tracking your search history (hypothetical example). The attacker could then log in later using those credentials and see what you searched for. It's a different, but very much related, CSRF attack, and something that you could mitigate by putting CSRF tokens on your login page, if that is a relevant use-case and this is something you care about mitigating.

Comment: @jeffsix- good description, although " If it comes back, you know that the request for an action to be performed originated with a form you sent to the client." - if it comes back it can mean that OR that the token was read on the wire and duplicated by the attacker. They arent single use so can be reused. Also the nice thing is there's a cookie that must be present as well which makes it a bit trickier.  if anyone is looking for more csrf and seeing it in action check out channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV333