# What's the approach to generate different AntiForgeryToken for each user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, csrf

I'm using MVC3 with Razor view engine.

I need to generate a different AntiForgeryToken for each user.

I'm thinking of generating a unique salt value and store it in users table when the users registers, and to use that salt to generate the token, but how can I bypass that salt value to the attribute `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. I think I need to define a customized attribute but I don't know how would that go (with getting access to user information to use the salt value).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't you just ask a similiar question?

Comment: You didn't really explain why you can't just use the default mechanism.

Comment: @MitchWheat No, that is a different question, read both well, I'm asking about different things. You may notice, it's not my 1st day on SO.

Comment: looks similiar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696520/does-it-make-sense-to-populate-an-antiforgerytoken-in-login-register-forms

Comment: @CodeInChaos, in the default mechanism, as I understood, I am limited to use a static salt value, I want a different one for each user.

Comment: I think the default mechanism has one token per session. And since there shouldn't be more than one user per session, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Don't use the salt. The username is automatically embedded in the token. There is no need to make a custom salt per-user.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a different salt, then you'll need to roll your own off the existing code or come up with a new scheme.

However keep in mind, these tokens are already user specific. Someone logged on as user A cannot use a token from user B's session.

Also note they are not one time use tokens, so what are you trying to prevent here? Make it so user A cannot generate one for user b? again - keep in mind user a isn't logged on as user b, so the check that is currently done would fail if this is forged.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very similar question with a great solution:
[runtime loading of ValidateAntiForgeryToken Salt value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994550/runtime-loading-of-validateantiforgerytoken-salt-value)

Basically, you'll just need to create an attribute that wraps the functionality of the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute, using a custom salt value at runtime.

Another great thing in that solution: the attribute can be applied at the Controller level, automatically applying to all POST methods.

**However**, as others have said, the MVC AntiForgeryToken implementation already uses the username in generating the token, so unless you have ulterior motives, doing this won't gain you anything.